# Constructing a recursion that forms a chain until no new element can be added

Tags: matlab, while-loop, chain

I have a matrix by 9x2 where the first column implies the second column, that is

```
A=[7 10; 1 7; 3 1; 6 9; 10 7; 2 8; 10 8; 10 4; 8 6];
```

I will form an implication chain using these data. Couple examples would be 3 --> 1 --> 7 --> 10 --> 8 or 3 --> 1 --> 7 --> 10 --> 4 or 2 --> 8 --> 6 --> 9

I tried to use a cell for every rule but couldn't form the while loop. The cell dimension changes with every new element but for example, I couldn't move from 3 --> 1 --> 7 --> 10 to two separate chains of  3 --> 1 --> 7 --> 10 --> 8 and 3 --> 1 --> 7 --> 10 --> 4. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to convert this to a directed graph. You can identify the source and sink nodes by those that only occur in the first or second column of A. You can then loop over all possible paths from each source to each sink node using shortest path.

```
A=[7 10; 1 7; 3 1; 6 9; 10 7; 2 8; 10 8; 10 4; 8 6];
G = digraph(A(:,1), A(:,2));      % Create graph
source = setdiff(A(:,1), A(:,2)); % Identify source and sink nodes
sink = setdiff(A(:,2), A(:,1));
for i = 1:length(source)
  for j = 1:length(sink)
    disp(shortestpath(G, source(i), sink(j))); 
  end
end
```

output:

```
 2     8     6     9

 3     1     7    10     4

 3     1     7    10     8     6     9
```

Comment: That would work great! I had forgotten to do it this way. Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately, my data is larger than this matrix. For some of the analyses, it stretches up to more than 50x2. So, the shortest path turned out to be the the direct path between two nodes. I'll try the longest path, though.